# QPropetyAnimation not working as expected in the mosemove event

Tags: qt, qt5, mouseevent, qpropertyanimation

I'm working on animations. So I'm getting some issue on this. I need to animate the screen with qpropertyanimation. Problem is When the user drag the screen through mousemove event, screen has to drag with respective mouse positions. If Mouse position will be middle of the screen then that time If he release the mouse, screen has to draw continuously. These all functions need to do by using mouse move events.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyll Im unable to implement the logic for this case. this is the reason i was requested some sample for this.